# Subquery or CTE to identify the mix of area in an extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table for which I am looking to create a new column, type which can either be "pure" or "mix" based on two different conditions.

| id | unit | area | n_unit | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1245 | 5485245 | A | 2 | 1 |
| 1245 | 2488754 | B | 2 | 1 |
| 2358 | 548754 | A | 3 | 1 |
| 2358 | 84447 | A | 3 | 1 |
| 2358 | 548754 | A | 3 | 1 |
| 4582 | 84447 | C | 2 | 1 |
| 4582 | 548754 | D | 2 | 1 |
| 9696 | 84447 | B | 2 | 1 |
| 9696 | 548754 | K | 2 | 1 |

I am looking to have a result as below:

| id | unit | area | n_unit | qty | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1245 | 5485245 | A | 2 | 1 | mix |
| 1245 | 2488754 | B | 2 | 1 | mix |
| 2358 | 548754 | A | 3 | 1 | pure |
| 2358 | 84447 | A | 3 | 1 | pure |
| 2358 | 548754 | A | 3 | 1 | pure |
| 4582 | 84447 | C | 2 | 1 | pure |
| 4582 | 548754 | D | 2 | 1 | pure |
| 9696 | 84447 | B | 2 | 1 | mix |
| 9696 | 548754 | K | 2 | 1 | mix |

My logic is this:

If all the rows with the same Id are either Area **A, C or D** then all rows with that Id are type "pure".

Otherwise, i.e. if a letter which is not A, C or D exists within the Id, all rows with the same Id are type "mix".

The n_units is based on the total units i.e. the number of rows with the same Id.

Looking forward to your kind help.

Comment: Why 4582 is pure?

Comment: @forpas, if A, C or D is pure other than is mix

Comment: Please show us your attempt

Comment: `select *, case when min(area) over(partition by id) in ('a', 'c', 'd') and max(case when area in ('a', 'c', 'd') then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by id) = 0 then 'pure' else 'mix' end from ….`

Answer (score 2):

It requires you one window function and one case expression as follows:

```
SELECT *, MIN(CASE WHEN area IN ('A', 'C', 'D') 
                   THEN 'pure' 
                   ELSE 'mix' END) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS type
FROM tab
```

If there's a 'mix' in your output, it will become the minimum value to be assigned to the partition, otherwise you will get 'pure'.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pKdraEv6ZrquenLMnYFU8o/0).

Comment: appriciated your kind response, i don't know if i'm right; you did post 2 options of result and you did delete one? or it's my imaginary ? thx

Comment: Just one answer of mine, this one. Hope it will solve your issue.